# How to provide assertion in Jmeter for SSO Login?

Tags: jmeter, single-sign-on, assertion

How to provide assertions in jmeter for SSO-login performance testing? In SSO-login all pages and data are encrypted then how to give assertion for that?

Answer (score 0):

Generally during SSO, there will a validation/Generation of Token.

So you can Assert text response for keywords like Token or keywords which should be there during SSO. Incase the SSO fail, the redirection will happen to error page, hence the above mentioned words will not be present.

The above explanation is with respect to SAML authentication SSO implementation, and mostly all SSO implementations work in the same way.

Hope this will help.